Can't install causal-conv1d on Mac M1 - packaging module not found?
I'm installing oython package causal-conv1d on Mac Ventura, M1 Silicon and I am getting an error about packaging module not found.
   pip install causal-conv1d==1.1.1 # or any other version 1.2.1 etc 

The resulting error message is:
  kages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
  [end of output] 
 × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
 │ exit code: 1
 ╰─> See above for output. ```


I tried all different versions of the package. Latest and 1.1.1 to latest. All give same error. I tried some suggestions found here: https://github.com/state-spaces/mamba/issues/55

but so far nothing seems to work.



You probably need this package https://pypi.org/project/packaging/

According to its GitHub-page the casual-conv1d package is "in CUDA" and therefore only compatible with NVIDIA GPUs (and seemingly it also works with AMD GPUs as stated further down on the page). Apple Silicon does not support the use of external GPUs so it is likely that you can't use the casual-conv1d package with your Mac.
(I do not have a MacBook with Apple Silicon to test this but when I run the code on an Intel Mac there is an Error that indicates that "nvcc" the Nvidia cuda compiler can not be found).

Upgrading setuptools from 69.5.1 to the latest available version (72.1.0) fixed the issue on my side (Ubuntu 20.04 + Python 3.11).
pip install -U setuptools

